# Number Theory $a$ coprime with 10

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

How do I prove that

$$a^{a^{a}} \equiv a^a \pmod{10} \quad \text{and}\quad a^{a^{a^a}} \equiv a^{a^a} \pmod{100}$$

where $a \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $a$ is coprime with 10. Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I tried using Euler's phi function on the powers but didn't get anything satisfactory. Thanks

Comment: @Morgan Rodgers Any idea how to prove it guys?

Comment: Yeah I have an Idea we reduce the power by $a$ and make the modulus $\phi(10)$?

Answer (score 2):

By Euler's theorem,

$a^{4} \equiv 1 \pmod{10}$ since $\varphi(10)=4$

which will give you

- $\left(a^{a}\right)^4=a^{4a}=\left(a^{4}\right)^a \equiv 1 \pmod{10}$
- $\left(a^{a^a}\right)^{4}=a^{4a^a}=\left(a^{4}\right)^{a^a} \equiv 1 \pmod{10}$

$\Rightarrow \left(a^{a^a}\right)^{4} - \left(a^{a}\right)^4\equiv 0 \pmod{10}$

$\Rightarrow \left(\left(a^{a^a}\right)^{2} + \left(a^{a}\right)^2\right)\left(a^{a^a} + a^{a}\right)\left(a^{a^a} - a^{a}\right)\equiv 0 \pmod{10}$

From here can you argue that $\left(a^{a^a} - a^{a}\right)\equiv 0 \pmod{10}$
$\Rightarrow a^{a^a} \equiv a^{a} \pmod{10}$ ?

e.g., since $a$ is odd, we must have $\left(a^{a^a} - a^{a}\right)\equiv 0 \pmod{2}$, then all we have to show is $\left(a^{a^a} - a^{a}\right)\equiv 0 \pmod{5}$, in other words, we need to show $5 \nmid \left(\left(a^{a^a}\right)^{2} + \left(a^{a}\right)^2\right)\left(a^{a^a} + a^{a}\right)$.

also, since $(a,10) = 1$,

- $a \equiv \pm1 \pmod{10}$ or
- $a \equiv \pm 3 \pmod{10}$

for the first case, it's trivial to show that both $\left(a^{a^a}\right)^{2} + \left(a^{a}\right)^2 \not\equiv 0 \pmod{5}$ and $a^{a^a} + a^{a} \not\equiv 0 \pmod{5}$.

for the second case, let $a \equiv 3 \pmod{10}$

$\Rightarrow \left(a^{a^a}\right)^{2} + \left(a^{a}\right)^2 \equiv (9^{a^{a}} + 9^{a}) \pmod{5}\not \equiv 0 \pmod{5}$ since for an odd $a$, $9^a$ has the last digit as $9$ (so will have $9^{a^a}$, s.t. the last digit of $9^{a^{a}} + 9^{a}$ is $8$).

Also, note that $a \equiv \pm 1 \pmod{4}$, $a$ being odd.

Now $a \equiv 1 \pmod{4} \Rightarrow a^a \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ which implies that the last digit of both $3^{a^a}$ and $3^a$ is $3 \Rightarrow 3^{a^a} + 3^a \not \equiv 0 \pmod 5$ (since last digit of $3^{a^a}+3^a$ will be $6$).

Similarly, $a \equiv -1 \pmod{4}$ implies that last digit of both $3^{a^a}$ and $3^a$ is 7, i.e., the last digit of $3^{a^a}+3^a$ will be $4$, i.e., $3^{a^a}+3^a \not \equiv 0 \pmod 5$.

Combining the above two, we have for any odd $a$ with $a \equiv 3 \pmod {10}$, we have $a^{a^a}+a^a \equiv 3^{a^a}+3^a \pmod 5 \not \equiv 0 \pmod 5$

$\implies \left(\left(a^{a^a}\right)^{2} + \left(a^{a}\right)^2\right)\left(a^{a^a} + a^{a}\right) \not \equiv 0 \pmod 5$.

Hence, in both the cases, we have $5 \nmid \left(\left(a^{a^a}\right)^{2} + \left(a^{a}\right)^2\right)\left(a^{a^a} + a^{a}\right) $

$\Rightarrow \left(a^{a^a} - a^{a}\right)\equiv 0 \pmod{5}$.

**EDIT**

We could also start from Fermat's Little Theorem:

$a^{4} \equiv 1 \pmod{5}$

Comment: This seems like a naive approach but I highly appreciate your time and efforts. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

By Euler's theorem,  you can reduce  the exponent $a^a\bmod4 $.  By Euler again, you can reduce the new exponent,  $a$, $\bmod2$.  But $a\equiv1\bmod2$.

Now for part two, apply Euler and you can reduce the exponent  $\bmod40$.  To do that, apply CRT.  So $\bmod5$ you reduce the new exponent, $a^a$, $\bmod4$.  And $\bmod8$, by Euler you reduce that exponent  $\bmod\phi (8)=4$.  In both cases you get $a $, as we saw in part one.

Comment: Can you elaborate the CRT part bit more? I highly appreciate your time and efforts. Thanks

Comment: When you apply CRT, you reduce the problem to computing modulo  $5$ and $8$.  And since you get the same result,  that's your answer.  It's the constant case of CRT, i.e. CCRT.

Comment: Also in the first part you wrote But $a \equiv 1 \pmod{2}$, how does this conclude the proof?

Comment: It eliminates one of the  $a $'s.

Comment: Yeah but how does it conclude the proof?

Comment: How does it show that $a^{a^a} \equiv a^a \pmod{10}$ where gcd$(a, 10) = 1$?

Comment: You didn't yet edit the proof

Comment: That's precisely what we were computing.   The LHS is equal to what you get by replacing the last $a $ by $1$, $\bmod10$.

Comment: Oh Gotcha! Thanks